# Clearing input on click space while typing

Tags: javascript

I'm curious about how to clear an input on space click while typing in that input. I completely have no idea how to do this. For now I'm at point as I can clear input while NOT typing, but don't know how to do that on the other way.

That's my code for now:

````
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="textbox" class="abc">
  </section>
  <script>
      document.addEventListener("keyup", event => {
        if(event.code === "Space")
        document.querySelector(".abc").setAttribute("value", "");
      });

      
  </script>
</body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 0):

You should use 'value' to reset your input element like:

```
document.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
    if (event.code === 'Space') {
        document.querySelector('.abc').value = ''
    }
})
```

In your code your are adding the attribute 'value' into your Input Html element, that is not the current value in your input html element.

Comment: Well, that's not exactly what I meant. I wanted to clear an input while any character in there is space. So for example, typing "abc " in input should change the value to "".